# To find last two digits of $2^{100}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, number-systems, decimal-expansion

To find last two digits  of $2^{100}$

I have just learned about modular arithmetic and I wanted to solve this problem. I only know about equivalence classes and about  $a=b \pmod n$. I have also learned about multiplication and addition of classes.  Can someone explain to me step by step on how to apply modular arithmetic to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607829/get-the-last-two-digits-of-16100-and-17100

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i need to know why and how of method and not the mechanical procedure

Comment: Gathdi, just try it out. Experiment what happens with exponents smaller than $100$. You will find a period. It is not very short, but not excessively long either. After you see what happens,  you can then take a look at it, and see what modular arithmetic is necessary to justify the result.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, +1

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What do you mean by period?

Comment: That you will find an integer $k$ such that  for all (large enough) integer $n$ the last two digits of $2^n$ and $2^{n+k}$ are the same.

Comment: Generally speaking, this website is not for giving lectures.  If you don't know how to do something as obvious as modular exponentiation even the normal slow way, then your instructors suck.  Given that you say you learned about "equivalence classes" without knowing how to do the basic arithmetic, that pretty much confirms it.  Your instructors are awful, look somewhere else to learn this subject.

Comment: @DanielV Can you provide some link to learn abou all this from beginning which has lots of examples

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Method 1(using fast power algorithm):

$2^0 \equiv 1 \pmod {100}$

$2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod {100}$

$2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {100}$

$2^4 \equiv 16 \pmod {100}$

$2^8 \equiv 56 \pmod {100}$

$2^{16} \equiv 36 \pmod {100}$

$2^{32} \equiv 96 \pmod {100}$

$2^{64} \equiv 16 \pmod {100}$

Since $100 = 4 + 32 + 64$

$2^{100}  \equiv 2^{4} 2^{32} 2^{64}\equiv 16 \times 96 \times 16 \equiv 76 \pmod {100}$

Method 2(using minimal cycle to improve):

Since $2^{22} \equiv 4 \pmod {100}$, $2^{100}  \equiv 2^{22 \times 4 + 12}  \equiv 4^4 \times 2^{12}  \equiv 2^{20} \equiv 16 \times 96 \equiv 76 \pmod{100} $

Last but not least: Since $2^{20} \equiv 76 \pmod {100}$, $76 \times 76 \equiv 76 \pmod{100}$, $2^{100} = 2^{20 \times 5} \equiv 76^5 \equiv 76 \pmod{100} $ by induction.

Answer (score 8):

$$2^{100} \equiv 4^{50} \equiv 0 \pmod {4}$$
$$2^{100} \equiv 1024^{10} \equiv (-1)^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {25}$$

So what number less than $100$ is $0 \pmod 4$ and $1 \pmod {25}$ ?

Answer (score 5):

$2^{100}\bmod{100}=$

$2^{10\cdot10}\bmod{100}=$

$(2^{10})^{10}\bmod{100}=$

$1024^{10}\bmod{100}=$

$24^{10}\bmod{100}=$

$24^{3\cdot3+1}\bmod{100}=$

$(24^{3})^{3}\cdot24\bmod{100}=$

$13824^{3}\cdot24\bmod{100}=$

$24^{3}\cdot24\bmod{100}=$

$13824\cdot24\bmod{100}=$

$24\cdot24\bmod{100}=$

$576\bmod{100}=$

$76\pmod{100}$

Comment: $2^{3 \cdot 3 + 1}$ should probably be $24^\cdots$

Comment: @mathreadler: Thank you, added the missing digit :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
 $$\mathbf Z/100\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/25\mathbf Z.$$

Now $2^{100}\equiv 0\mod 4$, and $\;2^{100}=(2^{20})^5\equiv 1^5=1\mod 25\;$ by  *Euler's theorem*.

So we have to solve the system of linear congruences: $\;\begin{cases}
x\equiv 0\mod4,\\x\equiv 1\mod 25.\end{cases}$

From the *Bézout's relation* $\;25-6\cdot 4=1$, we deduce the solutions:
$$x\equiv 0\cdot 24-1\cdot 6\cdot 4=-24\equiv 76\mod 100.$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{10}=1024$

$2^{100}=1024^{10}$

$2^{11} \equiv48$

$ 2^{12}\equiv96\equiv-2^2$

$ 2^{100}\equiv2^{12*8+2^4}\equiv-{2^2}^8*2^4$

$ =-2^{20}=-2^2*256=-24\equiv76 \pmod {100}$

another method

By euler's function, $2^{\phi(25)}=2^{20}\equiv1 \pmod{25}$

$2^{100}\equiv1,26,51,76 \pmod{100}$

$2^{100}$ is multiple of 4, so $76$.

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\ 25\!:\ \ \ \ \color{#0a0}{2^{\large 10}} = 1024\equiv \color{#0a0}{\bf -1}\,\Rightarrow$ $\,\color{#c00}{2^{\large  90}}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{2^{\large  10}})^{\large  9}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{\bf -1})^{\large  9}\equiv  \color{#c00}{\bf -1}$

${\rm mod}\ 100\!:\,\ 2^{\large  100} = 2^{\large  10} \color{#c00}{2^{\large  90}} = 2^{\large 10}(\color{#c00}{\bf -1}+25n) \equiv \color{#c00}{\bf -}2^{10}\!+0\equiv  -1024\equiv -24 $

Comment: All *mental* arithmetic, no use of Euler/Fermat or CRT etc (but of course you should learn those methods because they will be essential  for more general problems).