# How can I calculate $24^{33} \bmod 80$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can I calculate $24^{33} \mod 80$. I don't see how to start. I only know that $\phi (80) = 32$. A hint would suffice, thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607829/get-the-last-two-digits-of-16100-and-17100 OR   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1:** $80=2^4\cdot 5$ and $24^{33}=2^{99}\cdot 3^{33}$.

**Hint 2:** Chinese Remainder Theorem.

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

$\text{ }$

---

*Solution*: $24^{33}\equiv (-1)^{33}\equiv -1\bmod{5}$ and $24^{33}\equiv 0\pmod{16}$, hence by Chinese Remainder Theorem $24^{33}\equiv 64\bmod{80}$.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful.

Comment: We can eliminate CRT by using the **mod Distributive Law** -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Applying MDL $ =\, $  [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) $ $ to factor out $\,\color{#c00}{c=16}\,$ below yields

$$ \begin{align} \color{#c00}c\:\!a\ \bmod\ \color{#c00}c\cdot n\ &=\ \  \color{#c00}c\ \ (a\bmod n)\qquad\quad\  {\rm [MDL]}\\[.2em] 
{\rm so}\ \ \ 16\mid  24^{33}\Rightarrow\, 24^{\large 33}\!\bmod {16\cdot 5}\, &=\, \color{#c00}{16}\:(\ 24^{\large 33}/16\ \bmod 5)\\[.2em]
&=\, 16\,({(-1)^{\large 33}}\!/1\, \bmod 5)\\[.2em]
&=\, \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #0a0]{\!\!\!16\,(4)}
\end{align}$$

Note how much simpler this is than using CRT - it can be done *purely mentally*. As explained in the prior linked answer, MDL is an equivalent *operational* form of CRT, which proves much more convenient for calculations due to its operational form.