# What is the $10^5\pmod{35}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How to evaluate $10^5 \pmod {35}$ ?

I tried this $a=(10^2\cdot 10^3)\pmod{35}$
then again a mod $35$.  This is very lengthy please tell me a shorter way?

Comment: **Hint:** What is $$10^2 \pmod{35}$$

Comment: Easy to do this directly.  If you prefer, you can do it $\pmod 5$ (trivial) and $\pmod 7$ separately and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say "lengthy". You have $10^2=100\equiv30$, so $$10^5=10^210^210\equiv30\times 30\times10\equiv 30\times300\equiv30\times 20\equiv(-5)(-15)\equiv75\equiv 5.
$$
Either the above, or just do long division 10000 in 35.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

$$10^2 \equiv100\equiv-5\pmod{35}$$

and

$$10^5 \equiv 10^2\cdot 10^2\cdot 10\equiv-5\cdot -5 \cdot 10\pmod{35}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
10^2 \equiv 30 \left[35\right] \Rightarrow 10^3 \equiv 300 \left[35\right]\equiv 20 \left[35\right]
$$
So
$$
10^4 \equiv 200 \left[35\right] \equiv 25 \left[35\right] \Rightarrow 10^5 \equiv 250 \left[35\right]
$$
So

> $$
> 10^5 \equiv 5 \left[35\right]
> $$
>   ( and in fact $ 10^5=2857*35 +5$ )

Answer (score 0):

As $(10^5,35)=5$

let us find $10^{5-1}\mod\left({\dfrac{35}5}\right)$

Now $10\equiv3\pmod7,10^4\equiv3^4\equiv4$

$\implies10^5\equiv4\cdot10\pmod{7\cdot10}\equiv40\pmod{35}\equiv?$

**See also**:

[How to find last two digits of $2^{2016}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016)

[Get the last two digits of $16^{100}$ and $17^{100}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607829/get-the-last-two-digits-of-16100-and-17100)