# Calculate $2^{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{2}}}}} \mod 2016$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, power-towers

How to find $2^{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{2}}}}} \mod 2016$ where $2$ occurs $2016$ times? 

My current observations:

$$2^{11} = 2048 \equiv 2048=2016 \equiv 2^5 $$
and
$$ 2^{16} \equiv 2^{11}\cdot 2^5 \equiv 2^{10} $$ and now we have $2012$ of "2" left...

Comment: Do you have Euler's theorem available?

Comment: Yes, I had that on last lecture

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607829/get-the-last-two-digits-of-16100-and-17100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \overbrace{2^{\large 2^{\Large 2K}}\!\!\!\bmod 2^{\large 5}\!\cdot 63}^{\large\ \ \   2^{\Large 2K}\ge5\ \ {\rm by}\ \ K>1 }\, =\, 2^{\large 5}\!\left[\dfrac{{2^{\large \color{#c00}{2^{\Large 2K}}}}}{2^{\large 5}} \bmod\, 63\right] =\, 2^{\large 5}\overbrace{ \left[\,\dfrac{{2^{\large \color{#c00}{4}}}}{2^{\large 5}} \bmod 63\right]}^{\!\!\!\! \dfrac{2^{\large 5}}{2^{\large 6}_{\phantom{1}}}\ \ {\large \equiv}\ \ \dfrac{2^{\large 5}}{1}} =\, \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{2^{\large 5}[\,2^{\large 5}\,]}\ \ $  by

$\!\!\bmod 63\!:\ 2^{\large\color{#0a0} 6}\!\equiv 1\,$  so $\!\underbrace{\color{#c00}{2^{\large 2K}}\!\bmod\color{#0a0} 6_{\phantom{1}}}_{\large 2\ \mid\ 2^{\Large 2K}\  {\rm by} \ K>1}\!\!\! = 2\!\!\!\underbrace{\left[\dfrac{2^{\large 2K}}{2}\!\bmod 3\right]}_{  \dfrac{(-1)^{2K}}{-1}\ {\large \equiv}\ \dfrac{1}{-1} {\large}\ {\large \equiv}\ \  \large  2}\!\!\!\!\! =\color{#c00} 4$

Comment: We used $\ ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c) = $ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) $\ \ \ $

Comment: could you, please,  explain me why you wrote over $2^{2^{2K}}$ a $2^4$ number?

Comment: @jonnyWoox The overbraced numerator  is $\equiv 2^{\large\color{#c00} 4}\pmod{\!63}$ by the calculation in the line below it, i.e. by reducing its $\,\rm\color{#c00}{expt} \bmod 6,\,$ valid by $\,2^{\large 6}\equiv 64\equiv  1\pmod {\!63}\ \ $

Comment: @jonnyWoox Alternatively $\large \bmod \color{#0a0}6\!:\,\ 4^{\large 2}\equiv 4\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{4^{\large K}\!\equiv 4}\ $ by induction. $\ \ $

Comment: I think that I've understood all, it is very interesting observation @Bill - thanks a lot!

Comment: @jonnyWoox You can find many similar worked examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2059752?lq=1), some simpler than this.

Comment: I have one more question - why have you extracted $6$ and in which way $2^{2K}$ at top transformed into $4$? At the top we have $\mod 63$ and at down we have $\mod 6$ - why?

Comment: @jon $\large \!\!\bmod 63\!:\ 2^{\large\color{#0a0} 6}\!\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{\large \color{#c00}N}\!\equiv  2^{\large \color{#c00}N\bmod\color{#0a0}6}\equiv 2^{\large \color{#c00}4}\ $ by [modular exponent reduction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

Comment: And $\,2^{\large 2N}\! = (2^{\large 2})^{\large N}\!= 4^{\large N}\ \ $

Comment: I know but why you calculated $2^{2K} \mod 6$ and not $\mod 63$?

Comment: @jon We're reducing the numerator $\!\bmod 63$ in the first bracketed expression in my answer, i.e. $$\large \bmod 63\!:\  2^{\Large\color{#0a0}6}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{\Large \color{#c00}{2^{\Large 2K}}}\!\!\equiv 2^{\Large \color{#c00}{2^{\Large 2K}}\!\bmod \color{#0a0}6}\!\equiv 2^{\Large\color{#c00}4}\qquad\qquad $$ i.e. we have $\ \color{#c00}{N = 2^{\large 2K}}\ $ in my 2nd last comment.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $2016 = 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$.  Consider it separately mod $2^5$, mod $3^2$ and mod $7$, and combine using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: what can help me with calculate $2^{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{2}}}}} \mod 7$ with your advice?

Comment: $2^m \equiv 1, 2$ or $4 \bmod 7$ depending on $m \bmod 3$.